# C++, OpenCV : Assertion failed in Resize

Tags: c++, opencv, resize

As a C++ beginner, I am currently facing a problem I somehow can't solve, even if the code is pretty simple.
I've been searching for [answers](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2018/resizing-an-image/) all over the Internet, but none was applicable for my problem.

I am currently coding basic SVMs with C++, under VS2013, using OpenCV 2.4.8.
I was able to work on images of same size, specifying fixed height, width at the beginning of my code.

Now, I'm trying to : open images of different sizes, resize them to a certain lower size, and apply the previous code to the now-resized dataset. Simple as that.

Here's the beginning of my code :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(){
```

Input parameters are :

```
int Nb_Data_Class_1 = 10;
int Nb_Data_Class_0 = 5;
int Height_Zone = 200;
int Width_Zone = 200;
```

so I will resize all my files to 200x200 format.

```
string Path = "C:\\Users\\....";
string Format = ".jpg";

int Nb_Files = Nb_Data_Class_1 + Nb_Data_Class_0;
Mat TrainingMat(Nb_Files, Zone_Image, CV_32FC1);
Mat TrainingLabels(Nb_Files, 1, CV_32FC1);
```

For every file of the class labelled {1} - they are all named Tree01, Tree02, etc. - I open, and resize.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Nb_Data_Class_1; ++i)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << Path << "\\Tree0" << i + 1 << Format;
    Mat Image = cv::imread(ss.str(), 0);
    resize(Image, Image, Size(Width_Zone, Height_Zone));}
```

Things worked perfectly without the last line. I had a Mat array, filled with 0-t0-255 numbers. Now, I get the following error :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed <ssize.area<> >0> in cv::resize, 
    file C:\builds\2-4-PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\serc\imgwarp.cpp, line 1824
```

What could be the problem ?
I thought that maybe OpenCV wasn't properly opening the files ; but, in that case, how everything could have been previously working ?
Still wondering.

Any help would be much appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `Image` is being read..?

Comment: imread will fail silently, if the file was not found, so check the path again. also, what should `string Path = "C:\\Users\\....";` point to ? ( those .... look suspicious )

Comment: **@scapy :** I used `cout << Image << endl;` on a small-sized matrix to see what was happening. I observed a matrix of 0-to-255 number (not all equals to 0 or 255, by the way), so I thought imread was working.
Is there another way to see if it is the case ?

**@berak :** the path is : `string Path "C:\\Users\\Parveez\\SVM_Images"` for example. No \\ at the end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only reason for resize to crush is absence of Image. Even if you checked that some of the images were read properly it doesn't mean that all of them were - some of them may be missing. Reading files from disk is a very common point of failure for programs because you never can be sure  if the read was successfully or not. As a result every time you read an image you really really should verify that it is not empty:

```
if (Image.cols == 0) {
     cout << "Error reading file " << ss << endl;
     return -1;
}
```

Comment: I tend to see the check done like `if(!src.data)` although I don't see why checking `cols` would be any different.

Answer (score 4):

Not going to solve the problem in this case, but this assertion can also be caused by trying to resize a `Mat` with a signed type like `CV_8SC3`.  For example:

```
Mat wrong = Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_8SC3); // <- Notice 'S'
Mat right = Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_8UC3); // <- Notice 'U'

imshow("OK", right);
imshow("ASSERTS", wrong);
```

Note that checking `wrong.cols != 0` will not prevent this from crashing.

Comment: Can you provide your source? Doc for 3.0 (at least) does not say anything similar http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

Comment: @alpenwolf I'm afraid the source code above is the only source I know of.  Run the code and verify that you get an assert.  I found this out after I got the assert which led me here; I don't think it is documented anywhere.   This code was for 2.4, it may be different in 3.0--an update here would be appreciated either way.

Comment: I got the same problem with 3.2 . Thanks for pointing out this issue, this was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Your line:
 ss << Path << "\Tree0" << i + 1 << Format;

will produce (where i=0):
  "C:\Users\....\Tree01.jpg".

Solution

Change "string Path = "C:\Users\....";" line to:
  string Path = "C:\Users";

and
  change "ss << Path << "\Tree0" << i + 1 << Format;" line to:
  ss << Path << "Tree0" << i + 1 << Format;