# error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize' Recognition

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, resize, image-resizing

I was making an image recognition application and I had an error in the image reduction operation (resize) and i work on google colab here is my code

```
train_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/training_set/training_set'
test_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/test_set/test_set'

train_cats = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')

train_dogs = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')

test_cats_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'cats')

test_dogs_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'dogs')

train_cats = os.listdir(train_cats)

train_dogs = os.listdir(train_dogs)

test_cats = os.listdir(test_cats_dir)

test_dogs = os.listdir(test_dogs_dir)
```

An example of an element in the training game

```
train_cats[1:10] 
['cat.3910.jpg',
 'cat.3330.jpg',
 'cat.3288.jpg',
 'cat.582.jpg',
 'cat.3498.jpg',
 'cat.3744.jpg',
 'cat.355.jpg',
 'cat.3604.jpg',
 'cat.3807.jpg']
```

An example of an element in the test game

```
test_cats[1:10]
['cat.4001.jpg',
 'cat.4008.jpg',
 'cat.4003.jpg',
 'cat.4021.jpg',
 'cat.4013.jpg',
 'cat.4019.jpg',
 'cat.4018.jpg',
 'cat.4009.jpg',
 'cat.4022.jpg']
```

Modification of the training game

```
size=4000 
train_imgs = train_dogs[0:size] + train_cats[0:size]
random.shuffle(train_imgs) 
print(train_imgs)

train_imgs[1:8] 
['dog.1302.jpg',
 'cat.1396.jpg',
 'cat.3158.jpg',
 'cat.2907.jpg',
 'cat.1769.jpg',
 'dog.568.jpg',
 'dog.1743.jpg']


img_size = 150


#### On définit une fonction qui prend en entrée une liste d'image
def read_and_process_image(list_of_images):
    """
    La fonctionne renvoie trois tableaux (array): 
        X est le tableau des images redimentionné (resize) 
        y est le ableau des cible (label) 
        l_id est un tableau qui contient les nom (chien, chat) pour la soumission du script kaggle 
    """
    X = [] # On initialise une liste qui comprendras les images
    y = [] # On initialise une liste qui comprendras les abels
    l_id = [] # On initialise une liste qui comprendras les id (dog, cat)


    #### Pour chaque élement de la liste d'image
    for image in list_of_images:
        ### On ajoute dans la liste X les images redimensionnés 


        X.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), (img_size,img_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))  #Lecture et redimensionnement de l'image
        basename = os.path.basename(image)# On stocke le chemin de chaque image dans la variable basename
        img_num = basename.split('.')[0] # On extrait le nom de l'animal ie 'dog' ou 'cat'
        l_id.append(img_num) ### On ajoute ce nom dans la liste l_id

        ### On crée un vecteur de cible y pour les modalités "dog" et "cat"
        if 'cat' in image: ### Si la chaine de caractère "dog" est contenu dans la liste "image" alors on ajoute un 1 à la liste y
            y.append(1)
        #### Sinon 0    
        else:
            y.append(0)

    return X, y, l_id #### On retourne trois élements, les images redimentionnés, le vecteur cible et l_id

#### On crée trois nouvelles variables qui correspondent aux images redimentionnégges, à la cible et a la liste de modalité kaggle
X, y, l_id = read_and_process_image(train_imgs)`
```

and here is the error that i get

```
 20 
     21 
---> 22         X.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), (img_size,img_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))  #Lecture et redimensionnement de l'image
     23         basename = os.path.basename(image)# On stocke le chemin de chaque image dans la variable basename
     24         img_num = basename.split('.')[0] # On extrait le nom de l'animal ie 'dog' ou 'cat'

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
op
```

Comment: You can go ahead with @rayryeng way, it's more robust. Unless you are are absolutely certain file exists, you can use my way.

Answer (score 1):

Add a check to see if your image is empty:

Referece: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21596507/5671364

```
 Image = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
 if (Image is not None and Image.size == 0):
     print("Error reading file")
     return -1

 X.append(cv2.resize(Image , (img_size,img_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)) # Continue your work
```

Comment: `Image.cols` is from the C++ API of OpenCV.  The Python interface uses NumPy arrays.  Please change `Image.cols == 0` to what it's supposed to be.  This code will crash upon running.

Comment: Please note that sometimes `cv2.imread` can return `None`, so `Image.size` will throw an error because there is no `size` attribute for a `None` type.  I've removed my downvote, but be cognisant of this fact too.

Comment: Agreed, I think you have covered it pretty well in your answer, thanks. Upvoted yours

Comment: No problem at all.  Have a vote from me.  Thanks for the discussion!

Comment: Thank you for your reply I checked and it turned out that it is in the process of finding it empty the image list or when I list the contents of the list I find the images as indicated in the question above

Answer (score 1):

What is most likely happening here is that you are referencing an image that does not exist, so what is returned from `cv2.imread` is `None`.  You need to either correct the path to the affected file, or the image itself is corrupted thus returning `None`.  You can simply check the image to see if it's `None` after you load it in.  If it's `None`, skip the image and continue.  Also note that sometimes if the image is corrupted, it can return a NumPy array of size 0, so check for `None` and check to see if it's a NumPy array of size 0:

```
    #### Pour chaque élement de la liste d'image
    for image in list_of_images:
        ### On ajoute dans la liste X les images redimensionnés 
        # Vérifiez si l'image fonctionne
        # Nouveau logique
        im = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        if type(im) is np.ndarray:
            if im.size == 0:
                continue
        if im is None:
            continue

        X.append(cv2.resize(im, (img_size,img_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))  #Lecture et redimensionnement de l'image

        ....
```

Perhaps a more stringent check is to see if the file actually exists:

```
import os
...
...
    #### Pour chaque élement de la liste d'image
    for image in list_of_images:
        ### On ajoute dans la liste X les images redimensionnés 
        # Vérifiez si l'image fonctionne
        # Nouveau logique
        if not os.path.isfile(image):
            continue

        im = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        X.append(cv2.resize(im, (img_size,img_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))  #Lecture et redimensionnement de l'image

        ....
```

Comment: None is not particularly right as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23628409/5671364

Comment: @GaneshKathiresan Thanks - however sometimes `cv2.imread` can return `None` so checking for `im.size == 0` can still fail.  I would suggest using both.  Or even better is to check for the existence of the file too.

Comment: Yeah good point, I think checking if file is present is better.

Comment: thank you for your reply , I checked and it turned out that it is in the process of finding it empty the image list or when I list the contents of the list I find the images as indicated in the question above